# What does the name of the RF Missile mean?

Tags: jazz-jackrabbit

In DOS Jazz Jackrabbit, one of the five weapons available for the player character is **RF Missile**.  What does the RF part in the name of this weapon mean?

The weapon shoots two green rockets, one going slightly upwards and one downwards, from Jazz's rocket launcher.  This explains the “Missile” part, for rockets used to deliver explosives are often called missiles.

But the “RF” part is confusing.  Outside the context of this game, I'd take “RF” to mean “radio frequency”, which is applied to rockets that have steering fins adjustable during flight, and that are [controlled (guided)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_to_line-of-sight_guidance) from a ground station with a radio frequency communication link.  But this doesn't seem to apply to the weapon in the game.  The player has no control over the missiles once launched, and the missiles fly in a straight line no matter what, they're not homing to targets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RF Missile: The Really Fast Missile**

[(Source)](https://www.jazz2online.com/wiki/RF_Missile)

Hope his is what you wanted!